Selenium automation in headless mode
Has anyone come across this error before?
An error occurred: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=125.0.6422.113)
I'm trying to build a simple script that opens up google, searches for a topic and then prints something on the screen, just as a proof of concept of browser automation without the browser.
My script is here
enter image description here
Here is the output
enter image description here
I have added a print(hello4) so you can see where my error is occurring. I am able to get past the launch URL but then get the element not interactable error.
Have tried;
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

